# How do algebraic geometry and the Langlands program compare?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, langlands-program

At roughly 12:30-13:00 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOboYNh_5is&t=765s), Ravi Vakil suggests that algebraic geometry is a sort of unifying theory of mathematics.

In [this article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/math-quartet-joins-forces-on-unified-theory-20151208/), Edward Frenkel describes the Langlands program as “a kind of grand unified theory of mathematics.”

Is it possible to compare, contrast, and/or describe how these two disciplines interact (if at all), at a late undergraduate to early graduate level?

Comment: The main statements/conjectures of the Langlands program are phrased in terms of highly sophisticated algebro-geometric objects that have a lot of additional structure "coming from other areas of mathematics." I'm hesitant to say more.

Comment: There's a bit of a type error here. The Langlands program is not 'foundational' in the same sense algebraic geometry is. Algebraic geometry is a tool in the Langlands program...and in the study of rational poitns on curves and... The Langlands program, on the other hand, is more like a cutting-edge area of research.